# Как задать кастомные заголовки при каждом запросе по SOAP(WCF)?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Возможно кто-то захочет пометить мой вопрос как дубликат, но я видел все похожие вопросы и ответа в них не нашёл. Только поэтому и решился задать его самостоятельно.

Подключил к проекту WSLD'ку через Проект->Подключить ссылку на службу. Где-то глубоко в комментариях к какому-то ответу читал, что так делать не стоит и это считается устаревшей технологией, но ни подтверждения этому ни альтернативы, увы, найти не смог.

Сгенерировались объекты, всё прекрасно.
Не прекрасно то, что СОАП сервис, к которому я обращаюсь, не поддерживает стандартную авторизацию через указание у объекта Creditials, а просит запросить метод Login, возвращает токен и этот токен я должен прописать в качестве хэдера к каждому запросу, который я буду отправлять впоследствии.

Буду признателен за любую подсказку, как это можно сделать!

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю этот текст, но просто погуглил немного и нашел это: [How to add custom Http Header for C# Web Service Client consuming Axis 1.4 Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/897782/312041), [Support for Custom HTTP and SOAP Headers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb802855(v=office.14))

Comment: Видимо, в том и проблема, что не понимаете. Это не то, что мне нужно. Я не исключаю, что я хреново объяснил, могу попробовать сделать это получше. 
Например, в php я могу сделать вот так:
`$header = new SoapHeader('address', 'authenticate', 'value');
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);`
Мне нужно сделать тоже самое на шарпе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам ответил...

И так, механизм следующий:

1. Нужно создать класс, имплементирующий интерфейс
   IClientMessageInspector
2. Нужно создать класс, имплементирующий интерфейс IEndpointBehavior
3. Нужно их между собой подружить

В инспекторе сообщений заголовок задаётся следующим образом:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest( ref Message request, IClientChannel channel ) {
  
    MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader( "authenticate", "NS", "value" );
    request.Headers.Add( header );
    return null;
}
```

Затем инспектор привязывается к поведению:

```
public void ApplyClientBehavior( ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime ) {
    clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add( new ClientMessageInspector() );
}
```

И наконец, класс поведения нужно привязать к клиенту

```
client = new ApiSoapPortClient();
client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add( new CustomBehavior() );
```